# add_continuous_aggregate_policy does not exist, with timescale

Tags: timescaledb

One picture sums it all:

[image]

The function is part of the public schema, but is it not found; it happens whether I put 'public.' or not in front of the function name.

I'm using DataGrip and the autocomplete is aware of the function:

[image]

How can I call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `start_offset` parameter, please see the documentation page: https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/add_continuous_aggregate_policy/

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('conditions_summary',
  start_offset => INTERVAL '1 month',
  end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
  schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hour');
```